Curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ expressed as a bound on the rank of a matrix
Example 2.9 in Hulek's Elementary Algebraic Geometry is as follows: Consider the map $$\begin{align*}\varphi:\mathbb{P}^1 &\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3 \\ (t_0:t_1) &\longmapsto (t_0^3: t_0^2t_1:t_0t_1^2:t_1^3) \end{align*}$$ Then $$C:= \varphi(\mathbb{P}^1) = \left\{(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3) \in \mathbb{P}^3 \ \middle| \ \mathrm{rank}\begin{pmatrix}x_0 & x_1 & x_2 \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3\end{pmatrix} \leq 1\right\}.$$
My question is, how do you come up with describing the image of $\varphi$ this way? I can see how a posteriori to the above bound on the rank you can construct three quadrics (namely $x_0x_2-x_1^2, x_1x_3-x_2^2$ and $x_0x_3-x_1x_2$) from the minors of the above matrix and check that their intersection satisfies $(t_0^3: t_0^2t_1:t_0t_1^2:t_1^3)$ but how do you get the condition on the rank in the first place?

It says "the two row vectors are proportional".

@Trebor I know that.How do I go from the condition $(t_0^3:t_0^2t_1:t_0t_1^2:t_1^3)$ to the condition that the rows of the above matrix are linearly dependent?
I have already tried the following: If the rows are linearly dependent, $x_1 = \alpha x_0, x_2 = \beta x_1 $ and $x_3 = \gamma x_2.$ So we get $(x_0:\alpha x_0: \alpha\beta x_0:\alpha\beta\gamma x_0).$ This doesn't seem to help... Am I doing something wrong?

You might have misinterpreted what "linearly dependent" means... You must have $\alpha = \beta = \gamma$ for it to be linearly dependent.

@Trebor Ah. Embarrassing... Okay. So $a(x_0,x_1,x_2) = (x_1,x_2,x_3).$ I still have no idea how that comes from $ (t^3_0:t^2_0t_1:t_0t^2_1:t^3_1)...$

I would say this is just recognizing a geometric progression. If you need a way to come up with it that doesn't do that then I couldn't help.

My guess is that they started with the rank condition and derived the map $\varphi$ from that.

A more high-level (and a posteriori) approach would be to interpret the map $\varphi$ as the $d$-Veronese embedding of the projective line with $d=3$. What this map does, is the following: It constructs a polynomial ring with one variable for each monomial of degree $d = 3$ in $K[t_0, t_1]$, and then it mods out all relations among them induced by those in $K[t_0, t_1]$.
E.g. if we introduce the variables $v_{ij}$ for $t_0^it_1^j$, then we have the relation $v_{03}v_{30} = v_{12}v_{21}$ in $K[v_{30}, v_{21}, v_{12}, v_{03}]$. More generally, we always have $v_{ij} v_{kl} - v_{il}v_{jk} = 0$, which is suspiciously reminiscent of the determinant of a submatrix of the "big matrix of coordinates" $V = (v_{ij})_{i,j}$ (morally letting $i,j$ range over all integers).
Now, if we restrict this big matrix to a suitable submatrix with only positive indices, then we get exactly the matrix in your description of the map $\varphi$. This is somewhat heuristic, but I hope it suffices to get some motivation for the rank condition.
Final remark: If $d > 3$, then in an analogous fashion we get embeddings of the projective line into higher projective space (again cut out by a rank condition), and if $d = 2$, then we embed it as a conic into the projective plane (given by the single equation $v_{11}^2 - v_{20}v_{02}$).
